# Passing 2 parameters from Java to Python using them in python

Tags: java, python, arrays, python-3.x

I am passing string values to a python script from java. In my python script i am using the parameters but i could not able to read the 2 values.Plz help

Java Code:

```
String filePath = "E:\\Project_ivin\\test.py";  
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command("python", "-u", filePath, ""+issueId+""+comments);        
Process p = pb.start();
```

python script:

```
sys.argv[1] # issueid

sys.argv[2]  # comments
```

Comment: I am able to read 1 argument but if i try to read second one i could not able to read it..Pl help

Comment: how your are accessing value in python ??

Comment: A blank must be between: issueId+" "+comments

Answer (score 0):

Seems comma is missing, else use `3rd argument`.

**Java:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] list = { "python", "-u", "in.py", "issueId", "comments" };
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command(list);
    Process p = pb.start();
    System.out.println("" + pb.command());
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      sb.append(line);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
  }
}
```

**Python:**

```
# print(sys.argv[0]) // this will be file name

print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I am getting the arguments but when i assign those arguments to some variable i am getting error Ex: issueId=sys.argv[1] and comment=sys.argv[2]

Comment: what is the error ??